# How do I add font awesome icon next to Bootstrap button text in Ruby without it underlining the text on hover?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

So originally I had the following code for my buttons:

```
<%= link_to "Edit your profile", edit_user_profile_path(user_id: current_user.id), class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>
```

Which I changed to this to place a font awesome icon next to the text:

```
<%= link_to edit_user_profile_path(user_id: current_user.id) do %>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit your profile
    </div>
<% end %>
```

However, whereas the text before did not become underlined when I hovered the Bootstrap button, it now does. I tried applying the following in my CSS (I am using Sass):

```
.btn .btn-default .btn-lg .btn-block {
     text-decoration: none;
     
     &:hover {
         text-decoration: none;
     }
 }
 
 .i:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your link to this:

```
<%= link_to edit_user_profile_path(user_id: current_user.id), class: "btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block do %>
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit your profile
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was so simple I don't know how I overlooked that.